# Cannot publish to the device using AWSIoT for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, aws-iot

I construct the iOS application using AWSIoT.
I want publish the message from iOS app to my raspberry pi device via AWSIoT.
I can publish the message from myPC to raspberry pi. So, because of AWSIoT-sdk-ios certification problems, I can't move forward.

I consider two type. One is certification process with certification, private-key, rootCA. The other is using AWS-CognitoID.

If you understand how to write the code of certification of AWSIoT with certification, private-key and rootCA, or how to use CognitoID, Please give me a lecture.

Following code is current code. (this code is CognitoID process)

```
var iotDataManager: AWSIoTDataManager!
var iotData: AWSIoTData!
var iotManager: AWSIoTManager!
var iot: AWSIoT!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Cognito
        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
            regionType: .USEast1,
            identityPoolId: "us-east-1:MypoolID")
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
            region: .USEast1,
            credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        iotManager = AWSIoTManager.default()
        iot = AWSIoT.default()

        iotDataManager = AWSIoTDataManager.default()
        iotData = AWSIoTData.default()


}

//publish
func publish() {
        iotDataManager.publishString(mymsg, onTopic:mytopic, qoS:.messageDeliveryAttemptedAtMostOnce)
    }

//publishButton
@IBAction func publishButton(sender: AnyObject) {
       publish()
}
```

Comment: " I can publish the message from myPC"... from IoT console?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Not console. My code in the PC can publisht the message to the device. So, my swift code seems to have a problem.

Comment: and in your PC you are using the same user pool id/user? or a IAM user?

Comment: Regarding user pool, there is no problem. So, I want to understand whether this code is right or not.

Comment: the code seems right, check the IoT logs (change them to debug if needed). and see what the error says...

Comment: The problem was solved. I didn't write the connection setting code. Thanks for your help!